# Database as datasource to tree in flex

Tags: apache-flex, tree

I want to use Database Table as Data-source for Tree in Flex application.I tried to create XML file from Database table and provide it to Tree.But was not successful.
Please give me some solution for it.

Xml:

```
<node>
    <node labe="Some Data"/>
    <node labe="Some Data"/>
</node>
```

Mxml:

```
<mx:Tree id="tree2"
    width="567"
    height="527"
    labelField="@label"
    showRoot="true"
    useHandCursor="true"
    buttonMode="true"
    change="treeChangeEvent(event)">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection id="xmlListColl2"/>
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:Tree>
```

Comment: how did your xml looked like, also can you provide some as3.mxml code ?

Comment: My XML file Code is Like:'<node><node labe="Some Data"/><node labe="Some Data"/></node>'  This file I am generating from a database using PHP service. And mxml code is: '<mx:Tree id="tree2" width="567" height="527" labelField="@label" showRoot="true" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" change="treeChangeEvent(event)"> <mx:dataProvider><s:XMLListCollection id="xmlListColl2" /></mx:dataProvider></mx:Tree>'

Comment: @user1699408: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question by including the contents inside your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your Xml, label field is spelled as **labe** but whereas in your code you are binding **label**. Is it a typo?